# 'Undefined Reference to `vtable...' but virtual destructor present

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm currently working on an implementation for a game engine. I have a Scene class and a subclass of the Scene class called MainGame. I got the error in the title, so I googled it and added a virtual destructor to both classes, as google told me to. But I still keep getting the same error. Any help would be appreciated :)

[Console Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/osU3Z.png)

Scene.h

```cpp
class Scene
    {
    public:
        Scene(const std::string& sceneName);

        virtual ~Scene() { }

        virtual void Initialise();
        virtual void Update();
        virtual void CloseDown();

    public:
        std::string m_SceneName;
    };
```

Scene.cpp

```
    Scene::Scene(const std::string& sceneName)
    {
        m_SceneName = sceneName;
    }
```

MainGame.h

```cpp
class MainGame : public Engine::Scene
    {
    public:
        MainGame() : Scene("Main Game Scene") {}

        virtual ~MainGame() { }

        void Initialise() override;
        void Update() override;
        void CloseDown() override;
    };
```

```cpp
void MainGame::Initialise()
    {

    }

    void MainGame::Update()
    {

    }

    void MainGame::CloseDown()
    {

    }
```

Comment: You don't have `Scene::Initialise` and the other two functions defined anywhere. That's the error. You cannot just skip them. If `Scene` is supposed to be an abstract class, make them pure virtual.

Comment: For most compilers, the vtable is emitted in the translation unit that defines the first *non-inline* virtual function.  Declaring & defining an *inline* function won't emit the vtable at that point.  (If the class is entirely inline functions, those kinds of compilers will warn that vtables will be emitted in **every** translation unit.)